# Is it possible to handle webSetting In Flutter WebView [by webview_flutter package]

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

Here I include some java code from native android, I need to set those settings in [Flutter-webview][1]

````
        m_webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        m_webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        m_webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(false);
        m_webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(false);
        m_webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        m_webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        m_webView.setScrollContainer(false);```


  [1]: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter
````

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To check what parameters that available, you can press ctrl+left click button on the webview class that imported from that flutter package.

```
     const WebView({
    Key? key,
    this.onWebViewCreated,
    this.initialUrl,
    this.initialCookies = const <WebViewCookie>[],
    this.javascriptMode = JavascriptMode.disabled,
    this.javascriptChannels,
    this.navigationDelegate,
    this.gestureRecognizers,
    this.onPageStarted,
    this.onPageFinished,
    this.onProgress,
    this.onWebResourceError,
    this.debuggingEnabled = false,
    this.gestureNavigationEnabled = false,
    this.userAgent,
    this.zoomEnabled = true,
    this.initialMediaPlaybackPolicy =
        AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.require_user_action_for_all_media_types,
    this.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = false,
    this.backgroundColor,
  })  : assert(javascriptMode != null),
        assert(initialMediaPlaybackPolicy != null),
        assert(allowsInlineMediaPlayback != null),
        super(key: key);
```

luckily the parameter is still human language, and you can explore the available parameter as you need.